# Loop over data table columns and apply glm using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I am trying to loop over my data table columns and apply glm to each column using a for loop.

```
for(n in 1:ncol(dt)){
  model = glm(y ~ dt[, n], family=binomial(link="logit"))
}
```

Why doesn't this work? I am getting this error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , n) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'n' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..n]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
```

I nearly managed to make it work using something like `dt[[n]]`, but I think it gets rid of the column name.

Answer (score 3):

Using `lapply` to iterate over columns and `reformulate` to construct the formula.

```
model_list <- lapply(names(dt), function(x) 
                     glm(reformulate(x, 'y'), dt, family=binomial(link="logit")))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a formula with `paste` and use that in `glm`

```
model <- vector('list', ncol(dt))
for(n in 1:ncol(dt)){
     model[[n]] = glm(as.formula(paste0('y ~ ',  names(dt)[n])),
               data = dt, family=binomial(link="logit"))
     }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get a ` Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'y' not found `

Comment: @user572780 I guess this is the similar question you asked there.  It works with `as.formula`